# MySQL fetch array expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, api

```
<?php

include_once 'DB_Connect.php';

function getCategories() {
    $db = new DB_Connect();
    // array for json response
    $response = array();
    $response["Student"] = array();

    // Mysql select query
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Student");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temporary array to create single category
        $tmp = array();
        $tmp["id"] = $row["id"];
        $tmp["name"] = $row["name"];
        $tmp["number"] = $row["number"];
        $tmp["address"] = $row["address"];
        // push category to final json array
        array_push($response["Student"], $tmp);
    }

    // keeping response header to json
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    // echoing json result
    echo json_encode($response);
}

getCategories();

?>
```

I have this API for my Android app, but I have a problem with this error below. Any idea out there?

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>...\get_Student.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />
{"Student":[]}
```

Comment: why the android tag ?

Comment: use `mysql_error()` after the query to see what exactly happened.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty wait i research on how to use mysqlerror il be right back Suvitruf ,ubercooluk because i use it as API for android app

Comment: Why did you set tag Android?!

Comment: @HakHak `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Student") or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: @LatheesanKanes i think i will be able to play around with this now because i know what happened it says No database selected how did i not choose a database lol

Comment: See my answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_*` is officially deprecated. Use either `PDO` or `mysqli`. This is how you do it with MySQLi library:

```
<?php

// Connect To Db
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_database");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

// Query Function
function getCategories()
{
    // Init
    global $mysqli;
    $response = array('Student' => array());

    // Query Db
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Student";
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $response['Student'][] = array(
                'id'      => $row['id'],
                'name'    => $row['name'],
                'number'  => $row['number'],
                'address' => $row['address'],
            );
        }
        $result->free(); // free up memory
    }

    // Finished
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    exit(json_encode(response));
}

// Test
getCategories();

// Close Db Connect
$mysqli->close();
```

---

You can have this code:

```
// Connect To Db
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_database");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

In a file called **db_connect.php** and you can include it on the script you require db connection. Because the variable `$mysqli` is initiated outside of the `function() { ... }` scope; you need to use `global $mysqli;` to get access to it. This applies regardless of the connection code being on same file or being included from external file. Happy coding.

Comment: perfect i will study what you have written here so i wont commit the same mistake again thank you again sir happy coding