# Why is my php returning an empty JSON array?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to get Json data from Mysql using the following code. I've verified that the columns being selected exist.

I've searched several sites including SO and haven't noticed anything wrong with it.

I've used the example answer given in the following question:
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606729/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource)

```
global $mysqli;
$response = array('faqtbl' => array());

// Query Db
$query = "SELECT ticketID, agentName FROM faqtbl";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $response['faqtbl'][] = array(
            'ticketID'      => $row['ticketID'],
            'agentName'     => $row['agentName']  
            // 'name'    => $row['name']
            // 'number'  => $row['number'],
            // 'address' => $row['address'],
        );
    }

}

// I've added this but it doesn't help
//header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

If I remove `'agentName' => $row['agentName']` it works and pulls the data in this manner:

```
{"faqtbl":[{"ticketID":"8"},{"ticketID":"12"},....
```

I'm  using the following: **php 5.5.9, apache 2.4.7**

## **Edit Update:**

If I use the following within my while loop I get correct Data (without the json encode line):

```
echo "ticket: " . $row["ticketID"]. " " . $row["agentName"]." " .$row["ticketDate"]. "<br>";
```

Comment: What happens when you run the PHP directly in your browser? Do you get the correct results then?

Comment: Yes I get data correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Use [`json_last_error()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)
It should tell the problem.

Also you can use [`json_last_error_msg()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php)

Most possible that your agent field contains some forbidden characters.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm getting this now JSON_ERROR_UTF8 => 'Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded'

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Darhazer, i think you didnt understand the answer given here.

Comment: @TheCodingCat the problem here is not with php, but with data in your table. try to fill fields agentName with simple english names and the mistake should go away

Comment: @Darhazer any problems with reading posts to the end? I've written the mistake, just wasn't sure 100%. And this functions will be usefull for him in the future